# LoadBalancer 'EXTERNAL IP" is in pending state after I installed k8s using helm Charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I Installed K8S with Helm Charts on EKS but the Loadbalancer EXTERNAL IP is in pending state , I see that EKS does support the service Type : LoadBalancer now.

Is it something I will have to check at the network outgoing traffic level ? Please share your experience if any.

Tx,

Comment: is it always showing the 'pending state'?

Comment: Try this  command..I use this  in EKS 
```kubectl annotate svc <service-name> service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal=0.0.0.0/0```

Comment: how did you install k8s with helm chart?

Comment: @abestrad Yes it always shows in pending state - checking in further .. thanks  Avinash  Kumar for the command though

Comment: @AvinashKumar this describe command shows now that it is ensuring the LB :Events:
  Type    Reason                Age               From                Message
  ----    ------                ----              ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  2m (x49 over 3h)  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer

After running this command that you suggested .. but still doe snot show up the EXTERNAL IP , where do I capture the exact logs whats going on under the hood here

Comment: I think it is not getting the subnet and because of which it is not able to connect and get the IP, how do I pass the subnet for ELB ? All the annotations I see are for the ALB

Answer (score 2):

The `Loadbalancer` usually takes some seconds or a few minutes to provision you an IP.

If after 5 minutes the IP isn't provisioned:
- run `kubectl get svc <SVC_NAME> -o yaml` and if there is any different annotation set.

- By default services with `Type:LoadBalancer` are provisioned with Classic Load Balancers automatically. Learn more **[here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/load-balancing.html)**.
- If you wish to use Network load Balancers you have to use the annotation:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
```

- The process is really automatic, you don't have to check for network traffic.
- You can check if there is any issue with the Helm Chart you are deploying by manually creating a service with loadbalancer type and check if it gets provisioned:

```
$ kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 nginx --image=nginx --port=80
pod/nginx created

$ kubectl get pod nginx
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx   1/1     Running   0          34s

$ kubectl expose pod nginx --type=LoadBalancer
service/nginx exposed

$ kubectl get svc nginx -w
NAME    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
nginx   LoadBalancer   10.1.63.178   <pending>     80:32522/TCP   7s
nginx   LoadBalancer   10.1.63.178   35.238.146.136   80:32522/TCP   42s
```

- In this example the LoadBalancer took `42s` to be provisioned. This way you can verify if the issue is on the Helm Chart or something else.

Comment: Thanks for the details . somehow issue is still the same and investigating now at the HelmCharts level.. Cant I get the underlying logs / concurrent logs for why it gets in pending state ? like you know , what is it which is stopping it to spin the EXT IP. ?

Comment: You probably should reach your Cloud Provider Support, since the action of providing the LoadBalancer IP is managed by it.

Answer (score 1):

If Kubernetes is running in an environment that **doesn't support LoadBalancer services**, the load balancer will not be provisioned, but the service will still behave like a NodePort service, your cloud/K8 engine should support LoadBalancer Service.

In that case, if you manage to add EIP or VIP to your node then you can attach to the EXTERNAL-IP of your `TYPE=LoadBalancer` in the K8 cluster, **for example attaching the EIP/VIP address to the node 172.16.2.13**.

```
kubectl patch svc ServiceName -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer", "externalIPs":["172.16.2.13"]}}'
```